# Подскажите пожалуйста что не так в автотесте

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, gradle, selenium-webdriver, junit

```
    import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import static org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.titleIs;

public class MeFirstTest {

    private WebDriver driver;
    private WebDriverWait wait;


@Before
    public void start(){
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
}

@Test
    public void MyFirstTest(){
    driver.get("https://www.google.ru/");
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("cats");
    driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
    wait.until(titleIs("cats - Поиск в Google"));
}

@After
    public void stop(){
    driver.quit();
    driver = null;
}

}
```

На выходе вот это:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java" -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=62597:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.3\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.3\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.3\plugins\junit\lib\junit5-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\selenium-example\out\test\classes;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-java\3.11.0\5b50d4072e0e51779b6e9f3594106312061bfde\selenium-java-3.11.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\junit\junit\4.12\2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-chrome-driver\3.11.0\277f9f13a2ffcd7fa8268e2627610f4b69339664\selenium-chrome-driver-3.11.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-edge-driver\3.11.0\5fa855cf29defdfb6436addf731e4d79588cb1f6\selenium-edge-driver-3.11.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\3.11.0\72b783e0290721bc6c6ab71680257ace62fc35eb\selenium-firefox-driver-3.11.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-ie-driver\3.11.0\54055993f547a1aaa718dc18368ede146d379eb9\selenium-ie-driver-3.11.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-opera-driver\3.11.0\ac826e8224242ea60edbaa7dd2ae3f62ddcf731b\selenium-opera-driver-3.11.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-safari-driver\3.11.0\a6696382cbe6e88667abb925f5bce9f32aaad32a\selenium-safari-driver-3.11.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-support\3.11.0\2d0bdfbf26bfb3224c4c1b2fc52d43804ffaf25\selenium-support-3.11.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-remote-driver\3.11.0\3c8bdbd7c28a022ed0337958c82033405557d6f9\selenium-remote-driver-3.11.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-api\3.11.0\79a8a85e1f7c79968748a89d44cd1332098aca7b\selenium-api-3.11.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.7.9\51218a01a882c04d0aba8c028179cce488bbcb58\byte-buddy-1.7.9.jar;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.commons\commons-exec\1.3\8dfb9facd0830a27b1b5f29f84593f0aeee7773b\commons-exec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.3\d1577ae15f01ef5438c5afc62162457c00a34713\httpclient-4.5.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\4b95f4897fa13f2cd904aee711aeafc0c5295cd8\commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\4bfc12adfe4842bf07b657f0369c4cb522955686\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.code.gson\gson\2.8.2\3edcfe49d2c6053a70a2a47e4e1c2f94998a49cf\gson-2.8.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.guava\guava\23.6-jre\c0b638df79e7b2e1ed98f8d68ac62538a715ab1d\guava-23.6-jre.jar;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.6\e3fd8ced1f52c7574af952e2e6da0df8df08eb82\httpcore-4.4.6.jar;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.okhttp3\okhttp\3.9.1\84b4b7d1c4a238e7899972b7446c250691e65f1f\okhttp-3.9.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.okio\okio\1.13.0\a9283170b7305c8d92d25aff02a6ab7e45d06cbe\okio-1.13.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.code.findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\40719ea6961c0cb6afaeb6a921eaa1f6afd4cfdf\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.checkerframework\checker-compat-qual\2.0.0\fc89b03860d11d6213d0154a62bcd1c2f69b9efa\checker-compat-qual-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.1.3\39b109f2cd352b2d71b52a3b5a1a9850e1dc304b\error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.j2objc\j2objc-annotations\1.1\ed28ded51a8b1c6b112568def5f4b455e6809019\j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.codehaus.mojo\animal-sniffer-annotations\1.14\775b7e22fb10026eed3f86e8dc556dfafe35f2d5\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 ru.sdqa.training.MeFirstTest
Starting ChromeDriver 2.38.551601 (edb21f07fc70e9027c746edd3201443e011a61ed) on port 5402
Only local connections are allowed.
апр 18, 2018 8:36:33 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS

org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.551601 (edb21f07fc70e9027c746edd3201443e011a61ed),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: 'WIN-PESA5EN78S0', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.38.551601 (edb21f07fc70e9..., userDataDir: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 65.0.3325.181, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: e1eaac80a9d5574bf05dc9670039eb0f

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:279)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:83)
    at ru.sdqa.training.MeFirstTest.MyFirstTest(MeFirstTest.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Answer (score 2):

Возможно проблема таится в недавно обновленном selenium-webdriver до 2.38 версии. До обновления драйвера в проекте тесты работали без проблем, а после такая же, как у Вас, ошибка.

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5799 вот ишью по данной теме

Answer (score 1):

У вас ошибка при попытке клика на элемент `driver.findElement(By.name("btnG"))` - `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible`. Драйвер не разрешает кликать по невидимым элементам. Скорее всего, вы нашли не тот элемент, который хотели. Еще учитывайте, что при вводе появляется список с вариантами поиска, который перекрывает кнопку поиска. Можно попробовать так:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("cats");
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE); //убираем всплывающий список
driver.findElement(By.name("btnK")).click();
```

Comment: Помогло! Спасибо вам большое!